# how ffmpeg internally works to create clip from remote videos

Tags: ffmpeg

We needed to create clips from the remote video by providing the time duration. This is the command we are using

```
ffmpeg -i {{remote_video}} -ss {{start_time}} -flush_packets 1 -codec copy -t {{duration}} -y {{output_file}}
```

What We are unable to figure out is how actually FFmpeg does this. It does not download the entire video & still is able to generate clip for remote video.

Looked into documentation but found none.

Comment: There are a lot of modular components involved - exactly which are used depends on the parameters - input file type, location, output file type, codecs..etc.

Comment: Yup, I know & my question is about that only. I want to know what they actually do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it will be a combination of container format and what "protocol" that is used. The container needs to support some kind of seeking and then the protocol used (file, http, etc) needs to support seek. For example the ffmpeg http protocol implementation can do seeks using the `Range`-header if the remote server supports is.

Have look at https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavformat/http.c if you want to see how it works for http (search for "seek").

Comment: Thank you so much for taking your time to explain it. Can you please point me to the code, where is converts timestamp to starting byte and end byte? I looked into it, but wasn't able to figure it out.

Comment: I think what your looking for is how different demuxers go from timestamp to byte positions. Here is the mp3 and mov (mp4) demuxer seek implementation in ffmpeg https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavformat/mov.c#L7863 https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavformat/mp3dec.c#L532

Comment: Thank You so much for your time & effort.

Comment: No problem! i like to digg into ffmpeg stuff :)